# After overriding module-catalog/final_price.phtml 'From price' 'disappears from configurable products

Tags: module, configurable-product, catalog, magento2.4, overriding

My override of module-catalog/final_price.phtml makes the 'From' disappear from the price for configurable products. module-configurable-product too has a final_price.phtml in the same path as module-catalog **/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**. Can't figure out why module-configurable-product is not using it's own final_price.phtml anymore if i override module-catalog.

Note: In german it says "Ab 15,99 €" for a configurable product for example, but the "Ab" is gone after override.

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyVendor_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Eav" />
        <module name="Magento_Cms" />
        <module name="Magento_Indexer" />
        <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
    </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">MyVendor_MyModule::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```